# I'm trying to shadow find-file in Emacs, why is this function yelling at me about arguments?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm a recent convert to Evil-mode from Vim and I'm trying to make the environment more familiar. One of the things I miss is the `find` command in Vim. I'm trying to set up something similar in Emacs by wrapping the `find-file` command in a function. So far I have this:

```
(defun find nil
  "Shadow vim find command, with helm."
  (interactive)
  (find-file))
```

When I run the command it yells at me, `Wrong number of arguments {doc string} 0` I've tried adding arguments and had no success. The really confusing bit is that I shadowed a helm function the same way and it worked, like this:

```
(defun buflist nil
  "List buffers in helm."
  (interactive)
  (helm-buffers-list))
```

What's different? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find-file` needs arguments, you can't call it just like

```
(find-file)
```

The debugger shows what arguments are needed:

```
(filename &optional wildcards)
```

You can also invoke help to see them: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

Another option is to use `call-interactively`:

```
(call-interactively 'find-file)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll have to learn how to learn use the debugger.

Comment: Just write `(find-file)` and press `C-x` `C-e`.

Answer (score 3):

`find-file` takes a file name as argument, you will want to get familiar with `C-h f` to lookup up function documentation.

`interactive` can take arguments, for example,

```
(defun find (filename)
  (interactive "F")
  (find-file filename))
```

Comment: You may alternatively wish to use `(call-interactively #'find-file)` rather than obtaining and passing arguments yourself.